# How to change color on php text?

Tags: php, html

**i can't change color on - kr " .$row['pris'];**

```
echo "<strong id = 'thumbnailpris'>Pris: </strong> Kr " .$row['pris'];
echo "<strong id = 'thumbnailpris'>Pris: </strong>""<p id = 'pris'Kr "  .$row['pris']</p>";
```

Comment: Perhaps learning a bit about HTML and maybe CSS?

Comment: I see the closing p tag but where's the opening p tag??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `<span>` like this

```
echo "<span class='mySpan'><strong id = 'thumbnailpris'>Pris: </strong> Kr " .$row['pris']."</span>";
echo "<span class='mySpan'><strong id = 'thumbnailpris'>Pris: </strong>""<p id = 'pris'Kr "  .$row['pris']."</p></span>";
```

and add css to `mySpan` like

```
.mySpan{
color:red;
}
```